# Is there any class in MvvmCross that inherits from ActionBarActivity?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm developing an App with Xamarin.Android (aka MonoDroid), using the great MvvmCross Framework. The application uses Fragments, and need an ActionBar.

I've noticed that the `MvxFragmentActivity` inherits from [MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/162a816d148df224df0b8f635aeafe30c0910de9/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging/MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity.cs), and this last inherits from `FragmentActivity`, which has no ActionBar support. To support ActionBar, i need a class that inherits from [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), wich is included in the Support Library, and inherits from `FragmentActivity`.

So, my question is: Is there any MvvmCross class that Inherits from `ActionBarActivity`?

If not,

Can I just create a `MvxEventSourceActionBarActivity` and a `MvxActionBarActivity` that inherits from the first one, with just the same code of the `MvxEventSourceFragmentActivity` and `MvxFragmentActivity` just changing the inherits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is "No. There's no existing class. But I f you want to add binding to any Activity, then you can do so using 2 layers of inheritance - adding first an eventsource and then an Mvx layer"

There is a bit more detail about this in a few questions - eg [ActionBarSherlock with latest MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801728/actionbarsherlock-with-latest-mvvmcross)

For the latest android support library, there is one issue to be aware of currently - when building binaries you currently either have to choose the mono library which gives you compatibility with play services or you have to choose the new Xamarin component which gives you the latest support lib - see [MvvmCross - trying to use Fragments AND latest support lib results in linking problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125901/mvvmcross-trying-to-use-fragments-and-latest-support-lib-results-in-linking-pr) and https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15205

Comment: if i just do not need a _Support Fragment_, just a _Fragment_ (Android 4 or higher), is there any class in MvvmCross to work with ?