# fragment support compilation errors

Tags: mvvmcross

I have an Android app which uses:

- ActionBarSherlock Xamarin component
- MvvmCross fragment support.

I just upgraded to MvvmCross 3.1.1 and I get some errors:

> Error 2   The type 'Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> Error 3   The type 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I delete bin and obj folders just to be sure and rebuilt, same errors.

If I add the Android Support Library v4 Xamarin component, I get a many errors like

> Error 11  The type 'Android.Support.V4.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle'
>   exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.3\Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll'
>   and
>   '..\xamandroidsupportv4-18-4.18.1\lib\android\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll' 
>   ..MyActionBarDrawerToggle.cs  19  44

If I remove the Mono.Android.Support.v4 I got error which asks me to put it back.

Comment: You need to move so that all your libraries which use the newly branded `Xamarin` support assemnbly - see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15205

Comment: thanks Stuart but I don't understand what I should do. Do I need to recompile MvvmCross Droid Fragging plugin from source code?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what has changed with the latest version of MvvmCross, why didn't I have this problem before?

Comment: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/311-pushed-to-binaries-and-to-nuget.html - "Fragging now uses the Google Xamarin.Android v4 support library rather than the Mono.Android one." - Mono-to-Xamarin names changed on everyone - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125901/mvvmcross-trying-to-use-fragments-and-latest-support-lib-results-in-linking-pr

Comment: thanks. problem is ActionBarSherlock Xamarin component is build with Mono.Android v4. I tried to replace it with Xamarin Android v4 and the sample doesn't work. And I am in hurry with getting a new build. I'm now considering reverting back to the previous version of Mvvmcross.

Comment: Hello guys, whenever we release an update to Support Libraries we update All the components that rely on them i.e. GPS, ActionBar etc. Stay tuned since a new version of support libraries rev 19 is coming in the upcoming weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an old version of ActionBar Sherlock component that references Mono.Android.Support.v4, the [latest version 4.4.0.2](https://components.xamarin.com/view/XamarinActionBarSherlock) uses the new Android Support Library.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Alex

Comment: Thanks so much! When was the component updated !? I didn't see any updates in Visual Studio, are there notifications or any versioning for Xamarin Components in Visual Studio? Also, I was misguided that on Github, it is still the version with Mono.Android.Support.v4 https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlock.csproj#L45 I guess they didn't update the source code, just the component !?